# the SET methods in iOS when I enable ARC

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

Without ARC I write the set methods like this

```
- (void)setArr:(NSMutableArray *)arr
{
    _arr = [arr retain];
}
```

but Xcode tell me "'retain' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode" when enable ARC.

Comment: Just do `_arr = arr;`. And why do you even implement the setter like this? Just let it synthesize.

Comment: That wasn't a very good setter to begin with.  Pre-ARC it would cause a leak if you set first to one value, then another.

Comment: If you make your setters without ARC this way, you have probably a pretty big memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for your remind,I forgot release the old variable.I was actually write if(_arr){[arr release];} before _arr = [arr retain]; And now in the ARC project it's _arr = arr;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using arc, all you have to do is let the system handle the retain/release, this means:

```
- (void)setArr:(NSMutableArray *)arr
{
    _arr = arr;
}
```

However, if your setter is as simple as this its just easier to let the compiler synthesize it.

Previously you had to use @synthesize, but now declaring it as a property on the header is enough.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arr;
```

Answer (score 3):

`_arr = arr;` is all that is necessary. But practically, based on your code sample, there is no need to write the setter yourself. Simply declaring `@property NSMutableArray *arr;` in your header file is enough for the compiler to generate the setter and getter. When compiling with **ARC** enabled, retain and release calls are generated by the compiler for you.